# Get () method returning null in joomla when trying to apply filters

Tags: joomla

does anyone work with Joomla? I'm having problems with the following screen:

[Error mesage] https://i.stack.imgur.com/COlZQ.png

The code is wrong on this line:

```
$ordenarCol = $this->estado->get('list.ordering', 'texto');
$ordenarDir = $this->estado->get('list.direction', 'ASC');
```

I'm without guidance, I'm just following this article: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_decorations_to_the_backend

But even so, it still goes wrong, what could it be? If you want more details, I can send it.

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post all of your Joomla questions and answers there.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, he basically doesn't accept any kind of nomenclature. It must be `$ this->state`. Not as above that is `$this->estado`.